# NgbModule ng-bootstrap for angular2 is not working

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Imported it in app.module.ts like,

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

added it in

```
imports:[NgbModule.forRoot()]
```

while compiling it is giving

```
WARNING in ./~/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker-input.js
188:12-21 "export 'Renderer2' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/modal/modal-window.js
61:12-21 "export 'Renderer2' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/popover/popover.js
119:12-21 "export 'Renderer2' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/buttons/radio.js
108:12-21 "export 'Renderer2' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/buttons/radio.js
212:12-21 "export 'Renderer2' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead.js
224:12-21 "export 'Renderer2' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./~/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/tooltip/tooltip.js
131:12-21 "export 'Renderer2' was not found in '@angular/core'
webpack: Compiled with warnings.
```

What could be wrong with the initialization, can anyone help?
Thank you.

Comment: Which version angular are you using?

Comment: It should work if you use angular ^4.0 rc.1: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400-rc3-2017-03-10

Comment: i'm using 2.4.0

Comment: @yurzui  It will not work with 2.4.0?

Comment: Try @ng-bootstrap 1.0.0-alpha.24 or update angular

Comment: I'm using  @ng-bootstrap 1.0.0-alpha.26

Comment: I see. Since 1.0.0-alpha.25 ng-bootstrap requires a minimal version of Angular 4.0.3

Comment: 1.0.0-alpha.24  not working either

Comment: Then update angular

Comment: update to 4.0? is there any alternative to this?

Comment: `1.0.0-alpha.24 not working either` I don't see Renderer2 in this version https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/1.0.0-alpha.24/src/popover/popover.ts#L11 And 1.0.0-alpha.25 should seems also work

Comment: Let me try uninstalling and install it again

Comment: I would remove `node_modules/@ng-bootsrap` folder and run `npm i`

Comment: still getiing same warnings, how can I make sure it is 1.0.0-alpha.24?

Comment: I think removing @ng-bootstrap and running npm i is installing  1.0.0-alpha.26 again

Comment: I thought you had already changed package.json

Comment: I did change that but then also somehow it was installing 1.0.0-alpha.26. now it is working.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using

```
@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap 1.0.0-alpha.26
```

which is not compatible with angular 2.4.0

tried using `1.0.0-alpha.24` as @yurzui suggested and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I am using  "ng2-bootstrap": "1.1.16", with my Angular 2.4 version and it is working fine. Try that one.

Comment: this should be comment not an answer

Comment: Does not have enough reputation to comment, so before down voting see that also.

Comment: i haven't down voted your answer so far, just comment to let you know about this

Comment: Maybe add it as a comment now that you have the reputation