# NgbModule ng-bootstrap for angular2 not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-bootstrap

Imported it in app.module.ts like,

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

Added it in:

```
imports:[NgbModule.forRoot()]
```

> WARNING in ./~/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/datepicker/datepicker-input.js
>       188:12-21 "export 'Renderer2' was not found in '@angular/core'
>
> WARNING in ./~/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/modal/modal-window.js
>       61:12-21 "export 'Renderer2' was not found in '@angular/core'
>
> WARNING in ./~/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/popover/popover.js
>       119:12-21 "export 'Renderer2' was not found in '@angular/core'
>
> WARNING in ./~/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/buttons/radio.js
>       108:12-21 "export 'Renderer2' was not found in '@angular/core'

While compiling its says this, what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NgbModule ng-bootstrap for angular2 is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44062698/ngbmodule-ng-bootstrap-for-angular2-is-not-working)

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs/examples

Answer (score 1):

I waste time to resolve this issue from version of Angular. Do steps below:

1. Uninstall your current `@ng-bootstrap`: `npm uninstall @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`
2. Change this line in `package.json`: `"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.24"`
3. Run: `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Please update into Latest Version of Angular CLI, then you won't get this error, I tried it, its working fine.

https://cli.angular.io/